Adding hundreds of millions of clauses crashes solve Pycosat
Adding a large amount of clauses just causes pycosat to crash without warning or exception. Basic example below.
import pycosat
pycosat.solve([[i for i in range(1,235000000)]])

I wondered if there was a way around this or to stop it crashing?

Consider solving it incrementally by dividing it into smaller subproblems and then solving them sequentially.
